# strange noise from modem's circuit ( not by speaker or buzzer)

Tags: router, modem

My modem produce some strange noise when switched on.Modem is currently working well but that sound always stays when modem is in operation(like transformer sound). It may be problem with components in circuit. But i don't know which one make that noise. help?

Comment: Is the sound high-pitched, buzzing, or crackling?

Comment: High pitched like sound in some chargers. and that sound is sync with led lights in modem.lol

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.Checked the pcb. Got one bulged capacitor (470uf 6.3v). 
Went to store and asked that capacitor but they gave me 470uf 16v.( They told it can be used instead of 6v)

I removed bulged capacitor and tried to turn on modem without capacitor on that place ( to check is it cause noise or not). But without that capacitor modem still make that noise, and modem is not working without that capacitor( All light  are keep glowing and nothing happen).

Now i soldered new 470uf 16v capacitor on that blank place.I cant believe that ,noise gone and modem working properly. Actually bulged capacitor didn't make that sound, it is only cause for that sound. Still now i don't know which makes that noise. Anyway now noise gone and works perfectly:)